# Type 'Observable<Observable<Object[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Object[]>'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

This used to work in Angular 2/4 but since I upgraded to Angular 7, I am getting this error throughout my application. What could be the issue suddenly?

```
Type 'Observable<Observable<Object[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Object[]>'


Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<object[]>'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'object[]'.
    The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
      Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Object'.
```

I tried using 'any' type but it still has the same error.

the affected code:

```
getProfiles(): Observable<any[]> {
    const _url: string = this._serviceUrl + 'api/GetUserProfiles/';
    return this._http.get(_url)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

caller method

```
 this._exceptionService.getProfiles().subscribe(data => {
    this.data = data[0];
    }
```

package.json

```
"@angular/animations": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/common": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/core": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/http": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^7.0.0",
"@angular/router": "^7.0.0",
```

Comment: Have you upgraded to [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) and the new version of RxJs?

Comment: Let me explain - it says that CAR is not a BOAT and cannot be put in shipyard.

Comment: I think this is not the place the error occures.

Comment: Can you show an example of where you're calling `getProfiles()`?

Comment: Updated and Antoniossss I get the error on ng build with a bunch of red squiggly lines underneath the affect code

Comment: You can't use operators like `.catch()` or `.map()` directly on an `Observable` such as the one from HTTP `get()` with RxJS 5.5+. If you look at the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library), you need to use operators with `pipe()`. Anywhere you have `.map()` or `.catch()`, you will need to change those to be [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). The Angular `HttpClient` [docs](https://angular.io/guide/http) and [tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6) have exact examples of using pipeable operators with HttpClient calls.

Comment: 1) You have to create a pipe, as @AlexanderStaroselsky says 2) can you share `this.handleError` too?

Comment: try to fix the RxJS syntax to begin with. instead of `.catch`, you should use `.pipe(catchError());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem before. Change your Observable to return any

> > > Remove the array brackets []

```
  getProfiles(): Observable<any> {
        const _url: string = this._serviceUrl + 'api/GetUserProfiles/';
        return this._http.get(_url)
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```